# (Deep Learning) Backpropagation derivation from notes by Andrew NG

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, mathematics

I am self-studying Andrew NG's deep learning course materials from the mcahine learning course (CS 229) of Stanford. The material is available [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes-deep_learning.pdf).

I have a question about the chain rule techniques used in deriving the backpropagation step shown below (Equation 3.28 on page 12). Specifically, I wonder how come $\frac{\partial z^{[2]}}{\partial W^{[2]}}=a^{[1]}$? Obviously, the result couldn't be a vector (i.e., $a^{[1]}$) if we differentiate a vector ($z^{[2]}$) with respect to a matrix ($W^{[2]}$).
[image]

Also, the notes subsequently says that the size of the two sides do not match up. This really confuses me: if the derivation is correct, then how could the sizes of both sides not equal (see below)?[image]

I will greatly appreciate if anyone can help explain the steps here! I spent many days and nights already but have no progress at all. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered it is vectorized derivation?

Comment: Media: Yes sure.

Comment: Consider that the size of what you are taking derivative will be the same after taking the derivative. The size of you $L$ is important here. it is $3*1$. It is multivariate calculus :)

Comment: I would step away from those notes ... do some research to grok just what backpropagation actually is and create an implementation then test it ... only then will you know enough to answer above question yourself ... intutive notion of backpropagation is not difficult

Answer (score 0):

this is probably quite late, but i wrote an article on this that might help

https://medium.com/@tunghiem2010/a-simple-exposition-on-andrew-ngs-backpropagation-formulas-e60367a848da

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/89692)